# google column chart change bar color not set dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

i want to set different column color . Only one color show in column . How i set dynamic color in google column color.
How can i set dynamic color of every column color .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Dashboard/mTotalFileRefWise",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ PhaseID: $("#Projectlist").val() }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r);
                        var options = {
                            title: '',
                            legend: { position: 'none', maxLines: 9 },
                            colors: ['#00c0ef', '#DD4B39', '#DD4B39'],
                             width:500,
                             height:340,
                            animation: {
                                duration: 2000,
                                easing: 'out',
                                startup: true,

                            }
                        };
                        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($("#TotalFilesRefwise")[0]);
                        chart.draw(data, options);
                    },
                    failure: function (r) {
                        alert(r.d);
                    },
                    error: function (r) {
                        alert(r.d);
                    }
                });
            }
            $("#Projectlist").change(function () {
                drawChart();
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried background-color?

Comment: No. i don't try

Comment: @journaltrend update with answer

Comment: i am not using table i am using google chart with dynamic column i don't know how much column . Code is already added you can see.

Comment: Here it is json result 
[["Category","TotalAmount"],["COST OF LAND",1572.2],["DEVELOPMENT CHARGES",54.1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `colors` configuration option applies each color in the array to each series in the data table
series are defined by y-axis columns in the data table,
which is each column after the x-axis, the first column
since you only have one y-axis column, only one color is applied

another method to apply colors is using a [style column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) in the data table

this allows you to define the color for each bar, right in the data table,
for example...

```
[
  ["Category","TotalAmount",{type:'string',role:'style'}],  // <-- style role
  ["COST OF LAND",1572.2,'#00c0ef'],  // <-- bar color
  ["DEVELOPMENT CHARGES",54.1,'#DD4B39']
]
```

if you don't want to change how the data is being built,
you can use a data view to assign the colors...

here, a data view is created, and a calculated column is added to determine the color.
the colors are pulled from the `colors` config option, based on row index of the data table...
(just be sure there are the same number of colors as there are rows in the data table)

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
  role: 'style',
  type: 'string',
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return options.colors[row]
  }
}]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var r = [["Category","TotalAmount"],["COST OF LAND",1572.2],["DEVELOPMENT CHARGES",54.1]];
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r);
  var options = {
    title: '',
    legend: { position: 'none', maxLines: 9 },
    colors: ['#00c0ef', '#DD4B39', '#DD4B39'],
    width:500,
    height:340,
    animation: {
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'out',
      startup: true,
    }
  };

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    role: 'style',
    type: 'string',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return options.colors[row]
    }
  }]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($("#TotalFilesRefwise")[0]);
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="TotalFilesRefwise"></div>
```

**note**: need to use the correct version of google charts,
the `jsapi` library should no longer be used...

the new library...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this will only change the `load` and `setOnLoadCallback` statements,
see snippet above...